# MongoDB not using /etc/mongodb.conf after I changed dbpath

Tags: mongodb

Ever since I changed the `dbpath` in `/etc/mongodb.conf`, MongoDB has not been starting automatically, nor using the new `dbpath`. Prior to the change, MongoDB would be running when the computer started and I was able to simply run the command `mongo` to get into the console or start my Ruby on Rails server with no issues.

After I made the modification (in order to switch to a new drive with more space), the only way I can get everything to work is by manually running the command `mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf`. If I don't run that, it doesn't seem like the service is running and running without the `--config` option give me the following error: `ERROR: dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist.` even though the config file says nothing about `data/db`.

Some other notes:

- In addition to changing `/etc/mongodb.conf`, I moved all files out of `/var/lib/mongodb` and into `/home/nick/appdev/mongodb`.
- I changed the owner and group from `root` to `nick`. Tried changing it back, but it didn't seem to fix anything.
- I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 Beta 1 and Mongo 2.2.0 with Ruby on Rails 3.2.8

Comment: What does dmesg or the log file tell you about staring mongodb on during boot?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to set the owner and group to `mongodb`. When I transferred the files to the new directory, I had set the owner and group to my user account `nick` and also tried `root`, neither of which worked.

To do so, here are the following commands:

```
sudo chown mongodb /home/nick/appdev/mongodb -R
sudo chgrp mongodb /home/nick/appdev/mongodb -R
```

To confirm that it worked, you can check the file permissions with:

```
ls -l /home/nick/appdev/mongodb
```

Comment: Nick...thanks for your update. Sorry when I read the issue a few days ago, I missed that bit in your original description where you changed the ownership. This is because `mongod` is running under the `mongodb` user, which is configured through the .deb package on install. You could also have left the directory as owned by Nick and given mongodb write permissions through the "group" or "all" using `chmod`.

Answer (score 24):

*A late follow up on the above question...*

I had a similar issue after moving the db to an ebs on ec2.

It turns out that just running mongod still directs the dbpath to /data/db/ (which exists).

The `/etc/mongodb.conf` is completely ignored unless specifically directed to.

I manage to work around this by using the directive `--config` or just the `--dbpath`(both work)
But was left wondering where does mongod takes it defaults from...?!

I was unable to locate and override these defaults anywhere.
Anyone ?

Note:
I am really annoyed by this behaviour of mongod...This is just bad design,and bad documentation.

Comment: Since this isn't a solution to the question, it's better left as a comment to the original question rather than an answer.

Comment: I'd be happy to leave this as a comment but to comment on other users' posts "You must have 50 reputation to comment"

Comment: @PeterFox What is the solution proposed here? The question already suggests that `mongod --config` works, but the goal is to get mongo to auto start on system startup and to use the correct db without additional flags. I appreciate the confirmation of the problem from kman, but this post seems to end on a question with no solution.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. There is different setting on my mongod.conf file and when it runs the db path , port number everything is different.

Answer (score 1):

After checking all permission in the data, journal and log folders as suggested, my problem was solved by giving permission to a lock file in the /tmp folder

```
sudo chown mongod:mongod mongodb-27017.sock
```

I was running it as a AWS Amazon Linux instance. I figured that out by executing as the mongod user as below, and then, researching the error code. It might be useful for other troubleshooting.

```
sudo -S -u mongod mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

[MongoDB 1.6](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/1.6+Release+Notes) is very old and the latest production version is [2.2](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.2/), which contains a large amount of bug fixes and enhancements since 1.6.

Am I correct that you haven't installed 1.6 via a package manager such as yum or aptitude? I don't believe there are packages for 1.6 at present afaik. Therefore, `mongod` is behaving correctly as you have not started MongoDB with a control script.

Please see this [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/) on configuration file options.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I have 2.2.0 installed, but I had checked my Ruby gem on my app for the version which is 1.6. The question has been updated. I did install via aptitude.

Comment: Can you put a copy of your config file on gist/pastie/pastebin and a larger snippet of the mongodb log file?