# how do I force the mongodb service to use /etc/mongodb.conf?

Tags: mongodb

Related question, didn't fix the issue: [MongoDB not using /etc/mongodb.conf after I changed dbpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568997/mongodb-not-using-etc-mongodb-conf-after-i-changed-dbpath)

On Ubuntu 12.04. `$ mongod --version` = `db version v2.4.9`

I'd like the mongo service to use /etc/mongodb.conf (I thought it was set to do that out of the box but apparently not).

```
$ cat /etc/mongodb.conf | grep dbpath
dbpath=/home/xyz/mongodb

$ cat /etc/mongodb.conf | grep logpath
logpath=/home/xyz/mongodb-logs

$ ll /home/xyz| grep mongo
drwxrwxr-x  2 mongodb mongodb  4096 Feb 19 11:58 mongodb/
drwxrwxr-x  2 mongodb mongodb  4096 Feb 19 11:58 mongodb-logs/
```

(the instructions say it should be `mongod` user but that doesn't exist, while `mongodb` does, instructions incorrect?)

But whenever I start `mongod` it tries to use /data/db:

```
ERROR: dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist.
```

I've looked in the init.d script and don't see any options for config path:

```
$ cat  /etc/init.d/mongodb | grep config
# release without the 'show-config' command (introduced in
    initctl show-config -e "$JOB"|grep -q '^  start on' || DISABLED=1
```

When I restart the service it appears to immediately stop:

```
$ sudo service mongodb restart
stop: Unknown instance: 
mongodb start/running, process 2495
$ sudo service mongodb status
mongodb stop/waiting
```

Is this a bug? It appears to be ignoring the config file. I know I can start it using --dbpath or --config, but shouldn't it be reading the config file if it isn't provided a dbpath? Since the service is failing to start (apparently) where can I find the error that caused it to fail?

Comment: @PeteGarafano "but shouldn't it be reading the config file if it isn't provided a dbpath?" like I said -- why is it not reading the config file? It seems weird that any tool would ignore it's one and only config file when not provided with an alternate.

Comment: Also, you missed this part: " If you installed from a package [I did, the PPA] and have started MongoDB using your system’s control script [I think this is the same as using the service], you’re already using a configuration file." -- except it's not using the config file.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the config file with --config?

Comment: trying running `mkdir -p /data/db; chown mongodb:mongodb -R /data/db` and then running `service mongodb start`

Comment: What I'm trying to figure out is if it just defaults to hardcoded values if you don't provide --config. The docs imply that you don't need to use the --config option.

Comment: @AlexejMagura that would completely defeat the purpose of changing the dbpath in config.

Comment: @Jcollum, if you want to be sure that mongodb is reading from the config file even when you start it with `service mongodb start`, then change the service file so that mongodb is started with `--config <CONFIG>`

Comment: I've just installed from the repos myself for the first time ever so Ill try this out, it should be running on your system with the config arg if you do `ps aux | grep mongod`

Comment: As can be seen when I do it: `mongodb  23017  0.3  3.5 520260 59656 ?        Ssl  Feb16  14:26 /usr/bin/mongo  --config /etc/mongodb.conf`

Comment: "then change the service file so that mongodb is started with" -- so the docs are wrong?

Comment: They shouldn't be, your mongod should be running with /etc/mongodb.conf, I just showed you my run line from installing from repo

Comment: Sorry I actually supplied the wrong output, here is the real one: `mongodb  23017  0.3  4.4 520260 76064 ?        Ssl  Feb16  14:27 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf` I supplied the `mongo` shell program

Comment: Are you starting that via the service?

Comment: Yep that is straight from the 10-gen repo as described in the docs

Comment: Same thing I'm doing, but it's not working. This is a fresh Ubuntu VM and a fresh mongo install.

Comment: If I use the service? Nothing. It doesn't start.

Comment: Ok check in /var/log/mongodb.log and see what config it says it is using there when it goes to start up

Comment: i.e. mine says: `Sun Feb 16 18:17:57.159 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/var/lib/mongodb", logappend: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log" }`

Comment: I think this is OT on SO it's administration, so it should go to dba.SE, right?

Comment: @mnemosyn could be yes, could be no; there's a lot of these kinds of questions on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem (on v3.2) which turned out to be due to an error in my `/etc/mongod.conf`. I had the following:

```
replication:
  replSet: rs0
```

which should have been:

```
replication:
  replSetName: rs0
```

Starting mongod via `sudo service mongod start` failed silently with nothing in the logs. Fixing the config allowed mongod to start.

This was actually on RHEL, and I verified that the init script was passing `--config /etc/mongod.conf`. I assume it's the same on Ubuntu.